# Enable local react application on https

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https

My local react app works fine with http and https://localhost works as well.
I followed this [link](https://gist.github.com/nrollr/4daba07c67adcb30693e)
but my react app at https://localhost:3000/ does not work with https. Tried searching through many blogs but got nothing. Any help is much appreciated here.
Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Does it response with any errors? 401 ex.

Comment: @JunBin : did not find any error...

Comment: so what do you mean by "does not work with https" ?

Comment: @jbcazaux : site does not load.

Comment: open up the console log and check the response..